# mllib KernelDensity error

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, py4j

I'm trying to use pyspark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity this way:

```
data = sc.parallelize([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0])
kd = KernelDensity()
kd.setSample(data)
kd.setBandwidth(3)
densities = kd.estimate([-1.0, 2.0, 5.0])
```

but eventually get this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         8 
>         9 # Find density estimates for the given values
>   ---> 10 densities = kd.estimate([-1.0, 2.0, 5.0])
>
> /home/user10215193/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/mllib/stat/KernelDensity.py
>   in estimate(self, points)
>        56         points = list(points)
>        57         densities = callMLlibFunc(
>   ---> 58             "estimateKernelDensity", self._sample, self._bandwidth, points)
>        59         return np.asarray(densities)
>
> /home/user10215193/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/mllib/common.py
>   in callMLlibFunc(name, *args)
>       129     api = getattr(sc._jvm.PythonMLLibAPI(), name)
>       130     print(api)
>   --> 131     return callJavaFunc(sc, api, *args)
>       132 
>       133
>
> /home/user10215193/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/mllib/common.py
>   in callJavaFunc(sc, func, *args)
>       121     """ Call Java Function """
>       122     args = [_py2java(sc, a) for a in args]
>   --> 123     return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
>       124 
>       125
>
> /home/user10215193/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1131         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1132         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1134     1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /home/user10215193/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       321                 raise Py4JError(
>       322                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
>   --> 323                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))
>       324         else:
>       325             raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o19.estimateKernelDensity.
>   Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method estimateKernelDensity([class
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD, class java.lang.Integer, class
>   java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
>     at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
>     at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)    at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I couldn't find anything similar here so if somebody can help me with this I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about the types:

- `bandwidth` has to be `float`
- `sample` has to be `RDD[float]`

So replace your code with:

```
kd.setSample(data.map(float))
kd.setBandwidth(3.0)
densities = kd.estimate([-1.0, 2.0, 5.0])
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you! I'm really fine now:)